# Estimating transition probabilities of a Markov chain with bayesian approach

Tags: bayesian, markov-process, transition-matrix

I am trying to model heteroskedasticity in time series data,and the volatility  $\left(\sigma_{t}\right)$ is taken as a Markov chain with two values $\sigma_{h}>\sigma_{l}>0$ with transition given by $p\left(\sigma_{t+1} \mid \sigma_{t}\right)$.

How can I estimate these transition probabilities with Bayesian approach?

Comment: Just like any other problem, by setting a prior on the parameter, i.e. the Markov transition matrix.

Comment: @Xi'an thank you very much

Comment: @Xi'an how can I also determine confidence intervals on the coefficients?